# Bootstrap Slider bar slide left is substract, slide right is add

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

If I slide left I want to subtract the value of the slider from the value of another tag and if I slide right I want to add the value of the slider  to the value of the other tag.

Right now it both subtracts... I use the bootstrap slider.

This is the javascript:

```
function subtractfromBeg(newValue) {
    var currentBeg = document.getElementById('amount');
    document.getElementById("amount").innerHTML = parseInt(currentBeg.innerHTML) - newValue;
}
```

This is the HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 teBetalen well">
        <h2>Scenario: @Html.DisplayName(Model.ScenarioType.ToString())</h2>
        <h3 id="amount">@Html.DisplayName(Model.Bedrag.ToString()) Euro</h3>
    </div>
</div>

<input id=@("ex" + teller) data-slider-id='ex1Slider'onchange="***subtractfromBeg(this.value)"*** type="text" data-slider-min="@(projectCat?.Min_bedrag ?? 10)" data-slider-max="@(projectCat?.Max_bedrag ?? 20)" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="0" />
```

The total is 300 000

[image]

[image]

I hope the pictures make it clear what I mean. How can I address the slider and make it sense it goes left so it adds up again ?

Comment: Instead of a screenshot of your code, provide it as text

Comment: Hi Lennart. Welcome - please read how to ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You need to show your code here not as an image. You then in the editor can turn it into a code block.

Comment: function subtractfromBeg(newValue) {
    var currentBeg = document.getElementById('amount');
    document.getElementById("amount").innerHTML = parseInt(currentBeg.innerHTML) - newValue;                                                                                                                                    
} 

Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to substract your slider value from 300'000.

```
var amountMax = 300000;

function subtractfromBeg(newValue) {
    document.getElementById("amount").innerHTML = amountMax - newValue;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response mate! my question was a bitt vague so I rephrased it. Maybe this helps you for helping me? :)

Comment: hmm it works the same as my code.
The thing is that the sliderbar adds up the numbers, so if I slide from 60 to 61 it doesn't do -1, but -61 .. also when I slide right it has to subtract and if  I slide left it has to add again, so it is flexible ..

Comment: Please add expected behaviour and observerd behaviour to both of your images. I still don't understand what you are trying to achieve exactly.